# Tagging modules in SVN via Hudson

Tags: maven-2, maven, hudson, jenkins

I am using SVN + maven + hudson/jenkins.

I am having 8 modules under one build. After a perfect build i am able tag it and publish it for a clean release. Its a happy day scenario

Here, My requirement is to tag only 3 newly built modules and publish it for a release. How can I tag only the modules which are successful via hudson/maven.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven [Release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) does this for you.